# Repeat-like copycat function for Emacs

Tags: emacs, repeat

I would like some copycat function, that takes the previous input and repeats it (like `repeat`), but does not get written over when something else is done, and thus remains repeatable. Anyone has any ideas?

EDIT: The way I intend this is to have some mode in which `D` keypress will act exactly like `repeat` (if some other input has been done, repeat that), while `d` will repeat the last thing assigned to the last `D` key press.

EDIT2: If I would yank, and then press C-x z (in my mode also bound to D), then it will repeat the yank. However, when I would move the cursor down, and I try to press D, it then repeats the down cursor. In this case, I would like the small d to do the behavior of the last repeat (that is, yank) while D would repeat the down cursor command. So, `d` would *store* the last repeated command, while D would repeat the last command.

Comment: No idea what you're on about.

Comment: It is not easily explainable, but please try to read it again.

Comment: `repeat` is a function, and `D` and `d` are key commands for that mode, if that helps in clarifying.

Comment: I read it a couple of times already.  Can you give examples?

Comment: OK.  I understand what you want now.

Comment: @event_jr I provided the answer for what I was looking for. It was a good learning experience. Hopefully this clears it up even more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best attempt. It works, though it didn't incorporate all the error handling that `repeat` has.

```
(defun Navi-repeat () 

  ;; Checks whether the last repeatable command is the same as repeat var.
  ;; If yes, set repeat-navi to that command, and call it.
  ;; If no, check whether the Navi-repeat variable has been set before: 
  ;;        If bound, call it.
  ;;        If not bound, 
  ;;          give it the value of the last-repeatable command, and call it.

  (interactive)          
  (if (eq last-repeatable-command 'repeat)
      (progn (setq repeat-navi repeat-previous-repeated-command)
         (call-interactively repeat-navi)) 
    (if (boundp 'repeat-navi)
    (call-interactively repeat-navi)
      (progn  (setq repeat-navi last-repeatable-command)
          (call-interactively repeat-navi))
      )  
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This was just too long for a comment:

It feels like you essentially want a shorter version of keyboard macros? I'll try to explain briefly, and see if it is close:

- <kbd>C-x (</kbd> - start recording the macro.
- Do whatever you want (may be just a single command). For example, yank something, i.e. <kbd>M-d</kbd>
- <kbd>C-x )</kbd> - finish recording the macro.
- Now you can <kbd>C-x e</kbd> to replay the macro (you can do other stuff after you've recorded the macro, <kbd>C-x e</kbd> will do what you have previously recorded (i.e. <kbd>M-d</kbd> in this case).

Maybe you can create a shorthand version of start-macro end-macro recording, if you are sure there will be only one command, but these are really minor improvements. Once you get used to macros, you'll do it unconsciously, so that one keystroke saved won't matter really.

Also, if I didn't guess what you were after, this may prove to be interesting to you: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Command-History.html

Comment: I am aware and a vidid user of macros. The difference is that with macros you have to have the intention beforehand, while this repeating function can be done afterwards and does not require that planning. The latter part might be useful though. I realize planning sounds funny in this way, but I do believe this is a different type of workflow.